# order by weight ASC - D7

Tags: 7, database

This piece of code:

```
->orderBy('weight', 'ASC');
```

orders the column by the weight ascending. However, the rows are sorted like: 15 - 2 - 20
of course this should be: 2 - 15 - 20

How can I achieve this, specifically for drupal(7)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the database is using lexicographic ordering, while your intention is to use numeric ordering. Numeric ordering is only used when the type of the field is a numeric type. Check whether the field is of a numeric type.